# How to set up local 0x API testnet on dev machine?

Tags: 0x

I set up local 0x testnet as described here-- https://0x.org/docs/guides/setting-up-a-local-0x-testnet. That works great. The document also states that the local testnet is pre-setup with dummy tokens.

However, I can't call `https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?...` because it, of course, doesn't know about the dummy tokens (calls return "insufficient liquidity" error message). I have two questions about this:

1. How can I set up a local API instance on my dev machine and populate with test liquidity for the dummy tokens?
2. Is there a different best practice for integrating with 0x in dev? (Maybe instead of setting up a local testnet I should do something else?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this was a local issue (mismatch of networks, 0xAPI mainnet and dev was testnet).

In general this should be fine to fork mainnet in hardhat and execute against it. The only warning I would give is to make sure the hardhat fork isn't too long lived. Prices and liquidity can move around.